# helm/rabbitmq-ha work with istio strict permission? do rabbitmq have a cluster announce ip var like redis cluster?

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing, istio

I am currently having problems with deploying `helm/rabbitmq-ha`. It does not work when `Istio` is set as `Strict` but only works when `Istio` is set as `Permissive`. The initial problem seems to be because rabbitmq uses `podip on port epmd for local redirection` instead of `localhost/127.0.0.1` causing the mtls connection to fail. I temporarily resolved this problem by "authorizing" this port (in other words not requiring mtls). Unfortunately, I receive additional errors. I am curious if the config for rabbitmq have something alike redis's cluster announce ip variable. I know the pod ip is likely lost on redirection between the envoys of two different rabbitmq pods. I think this might have caused the additional errors? If anyone has successfully placed `helm/rabbitmq-ha` on `Istio` with the `Strict Permission`, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There are three different issues that are related to running RabbitMQ with Istio mTLS.

1. - Stateful sets pod discovery
2. - Mutual TLS for POD IP communication
3. - Headless service DNS entry cannot participate in MTLS

All of them are well described and have workarounds in [this](https://github.com/arielb135/RabbitMQ-with-istio-MTLS) github project.

Hope this helps.